# Any tips for beating Malthael as a Wizard on high difficulty levels?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm playing solo as a hardcore Wizard on Torment IX, running Tal Rasha's with dual hydras. Usually when I encounter hard boss fights with melee bosses, I'm forced to kite and rely on my hydras + meteors to do the damage - and it works fine.

Malthael, however, is one of my hardest fights, especially in the 2nd stage of the fight, when he turns into a whirling thing and chases me around. He moves about as fast as I can run, the floor is full of bad things, and I can't teleport frequently enough to evade all that.

I just increased difficulty to Torment X and I'm fearful about approaching that fight. Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the easiest things you can do is to equip or cube the effect of the [Talisman of Aranoch](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/talisman-of-aranoch).  That completely nullifies all of the ground effects that he spams all over the place making it safe for you to kite.

To dodge the whirlwind attack, its best if you have(or cubed) an [aether walker](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/aether-walker).

Also, since I'm assuming you are playing on patch 2.4.  A [DMO arcane orbit](http://www.d3planner.com/243731909) wizard would kill him on TX in about 10 seconds.

Comment: Encouraging hint: Talismat of Aranoch has 5/292 chance of dropping for a Wizard, or 1,71% :-)

Comment: Cubing that Talisman made the fight significantly easier as DMO. The 10 seconds estimate was more like 2 minutes, but Malthael still didn't last long enough to do more than a single Whirlwind attack.